# Чем заменить setAttribute в IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
o = document.getElementById('callback_form');
o.setAttribute("action","handler1_bel.php");
```

Работает везде кроме IE

Как написать что-бы работало во всех браузерах?

Comment: какая версия IE? как определил что не работает?

Comment: Версия 11.0.9600

Comment: @ВладПаздников так бы сразу, а то я тут свои знания по некромантии стал вспоминать)

Comment: _как определил что не работает_???

Comment: Запустил в разных браузерах и нажал f12 ))

Comment: В одном action изменился

Comment: А в IE остался прежний

Comment: добавь [mcve] в сниппет в вопросе. Возможно не работает что-то еще. Пример в [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkL48kvv/) - работает в IE11 как и ожидается

Answer (score 0):

```
o.action = "handler1_bel.php";
```

Comment: Пробовал! Не работает!

Answer (score 0):

Надо писать вот так:

```
document.callback_form.setAttribute("action","handler1_bel.php");
```

где `callback_form` — это `name`.

Comment: `document.callback_form` почти ничем не отличается от `document.getElementById('callback_form')` за исключением того, что может и отсутствовать.